# symfony 2 REST and JS (ember.js) client

Tags: symfony, ember.js, directory-structure

I made a simple REST API bundle with Symfony 2 and now i want to use ember.js as a client.
I made a new bundle for it (ClientBundle). Where should i put the js files? Into

- the ClientBundle/Resources folder under public/js?
- app/web under  public folder
- somewhere else

what is the best practice / your favourite folder structure?

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to put the client code into a separate repository and use JS specific tools for its development.

Just because you can put them into a single repository doesn't mean you should. Imagine what a mess that repository will become if/when you add other clients like Android, iOS, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

We put the client JS under Bundle/Resources/public/ and have a separate frontend and backend bundle.  We just published a sample distro to show how this is organized here:
https://github.com/ucsf-ckm/symfony-emberjs-edition

Answer (score 1):

Currently the answer would be to store the assets in the /web directory. [Source](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html)

Comment: Agree, I will try with this recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend the `ClientBundle` to be reusable across different projects you may have, you are best served by placing the files into the `ClientBundle\Resources\public\js` folder.